# When the server is offline the application crashes

Tags: android, json

I have a problem because when I have my server offline the Android application tries to connect with the server and it crashes.

I think the solution can be to put an exception inside **`doInBackground`** into catch or check in **`onCreate`** if the server is offline or online with some function.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Provide the code what you have tried by now.It will be very helpful for further research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try {
            menuString = getStringFromURL(strings[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Error Connecting to server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }
        return menuString;
    }
```